# How is the easiest way to adapt this layout to orientation changes?

Tags: android

I have two views stacked vertically on portrait mode, let's say something like this

```
<LinearLayout        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

-----------------
|     view1     |
----------------
|     view2     |
-----------------
```

I need to show them in one line in landscape. Ideally like this

```
-----------------
| view2 | view1 |
-----------------
```

where `view2` has `wrap_content` width and `view1` fills the rest of the width

I'm totally free to change the parent `LinearLayout` or change anything necessary to achieve the objective. The root container is a `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: Put a copy of the layout in `res/layout-land/` and, in there, adjust your `LinearLayout` to match your needs. `view2` would have a `wrap_content` width and `view1` would use `match_parent` to take up the remaining space.

Comment: That's a nice alternative @CommonsWare, thanks. If there is any way to do it without having duplicated layouts the better... to avoid increasing the manteniment cost.

Comment: You could extract this `LinearLayout` into a separate layout file and have the `res/layout-land/` copy of just it. The layout that presently has the `LinearLayout` would need only the one `res/layout/` version, and it would use `<include>` to pull in the new layout for the `LinearLayout`. That reduces the duplication. The only way to eliminate it entirely would be to have a bunch of Java/Kotlin code that changes this portion of the view hierarchy at runtime, and that is likely to be more expensive to maintain than two copies of the layout. Besides, your question is for "easiest"... :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @CommonsWare, will be exploring that option.